# How to create this circular background image? (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape

[image]

I want to create this circular image.
But I am not sure what is the better way of making this.

I personally create this with a pie, with gradient end as a white but alpha becomes less than 1 (more transparent), as shown below.

[image]

Is there a better way of making this?

Comment: Are we supposed to see something moving here? IMHO PNG does not allow for animations - maybe you should use a GIF instead. A second issue is, that I don't know, what part is the background and which the foreground here (I guess the white part is the foreground) and why it matters.

Comment: @userunknown Sorry to say it confuses you. Right, i just mean an image (png), which i will do the animation with my program. I mean the white image to serve as a background in my program (the grey part is added here so the white color is visible). In short, i mean the white color image here, regarding 'how to create this'.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do beyond create an image with alpha (transparent) areas, and that it needs to be circular

Comment: sorry i shouldn't mention anything about 'movement' or 'animation'. basically what i want is that image only. i would post what i did soon.

Comment: @Pinback as promised, i posted my solution in the end. i just want the image.

Comment: @zeroflaw I've deleted the reference to a moving image. If you are not happy with the edit I made, you can revert it.

Comment: @BillyKerr No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the gradients in Inkscape. You can have more than two stops. Gradient stops can have 100% alpha.

The example below shows the gradient I applied to all the segments.  It has 9 stops, and 100% alpha stops at either end.

[image]

Comment: Omg. I feel yours is more accurate. Thanks for this :)

Comment: Sorry I also meant to say, unlike yours this is one shape with a gradient, and then I duplicated and rotated each segment repeatedly.

Comment: no sorry needed lol.

Answer (score 0):

[image: My Solution]

Sorry for the late. Here's my solution in the end. May not be the best. Let me know if you have a better solution or i will close this soon.

1. Draw a circle
2. Draw a straight line. Duplicate and rotate it. (Hold `Ctrl` to make it rotate at a fixed angle)
3. `Union` those lines. Perform `Path -> Difference` on the circle.
4. `Break Apart` the triangles. Remove the colors as you wish.
5. Create another circle, with `circular gradient` -> White in the center. Black at the outermost.
6. Perform `Object-> Mask -> Set` with item from (4)

Comment: This can also be done with simple gradients without a mask. I realise this is an old question, but anyway I added an answer too.